# Wifi Won't Work

Tags: wireless

I recently decided to give Linux a try, and wiped my hard drive and installed Ubuntu Mate 16.04. It will show that I have a wifi connection, but the internet will not load. I had turned off ipv6 yesterday morning and the internet worked for a bit, but now it's not working again. Nothing is hard or soft disabled, I checked the rfkill list. All of my other devices work on the wifi, and I have restarted the computer and router countless times. Any idea what can be the problem?

And I am running a Lenovo Ideapad 310.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 15 Feb 2017 11:36 EST -0500

Booted last: 15 Feb 2017 00:00 EST -0500

Script from: 08 Jul 2016 02:16 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-62-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 18 14:10:15 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

MATE

##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:384c]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8821]
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:a814]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0821 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:06b2 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 099: ID 1ebf:705b  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

rtl8821ae             225280  0
btcoexist              53248  1 rtl8821ae
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8821ae
rtlwifi                77824  2 rtl_pci,rtl8821ae
mac80211              737280  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8821ae
cfg80211              565248  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
ideapad_laptop         24576  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop
wmi                    20480  1 ideapad_laptop
video                  40960  3 i915_bpo,ideapad_laptop,thinkpad_acpi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp0s20f0u3 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp0s20f0u3' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:192.168.42.43  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::13f1:5fba:271e:9658/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:33112 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:26391 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:37280578 (37.2 MB)  TX bytes:6624185 (6.6 MB)

enp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp1s0' [IF2]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF3]>  
          inet addr:192.168.1.17  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'wlp2s0' [IF3]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6125 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1994 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1143860 (1.1 MB)  TX bytes:197425 (197.4 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.

enp0s20f0u3  no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"serenity"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.18 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'serenity' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=6 Mb/s   Tx-Power=17 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-39 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.42.129  0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s20f0u3
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp2s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp2s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp2s0
192.168.42.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s20f0u3

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search home

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       962     1  0 10:14 ?        00:00:02 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s20f0u3
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Android
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Android
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rndis_host
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 22-Aug-2005
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               RNDIS device
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp0s20f0u3' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/net/enp0s20f0u3
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp0s20f0u3
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       09b71e9f-c5d1-356b-b10d-d6f53864caf3
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/5
GENERAL.METERED:                        yes (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{5}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   09b71e9f-c5d1-356b-b10d-d6f53864caf3 | Wired connection 1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.42.43/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.42.129
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.42.43
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.42.255
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 3150
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       routers = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 1800
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       expiry = 1487179710
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       host_name = lucifer-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15IKB
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       network_number = 192.168.42.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       vendor_encapsulated_options = ANDROID_METERED
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       next_server = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 3600
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::13f1:5fba:271e:9658/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rtl8821ae
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.4.0-62-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF3]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:02:00.0/net/wlp2s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlp2s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     serenity
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       9a10ee6c-33db-4467-9870-cc28dc9c67a7
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     6 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   9a10ee6c-33db-4467-9870-cc28dc9c67a7 | serenity
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.17/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          home
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.1.17
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        time_offset = 0
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 3150
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 1800
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       domain_name = home
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       expiry = 1487179681
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       host_name = lucifer-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15IKB
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       network_number = 192.168.1.0
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       ntp_servers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 3600
DHCP4.OPTION[32]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[33]:                       next_server = 192.168.1.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::<IP6 'wlp2s0' [IF3]>/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp1s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp1s0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/net/enp1s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

SSID               BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  * 
optimumwifi        <MAC 'optimumwifi' [AC4]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  --         no        
serenity           <MAC 'serenity' [AC3]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2  no        
optimumwifi        <MAC 'optimumwifi' [AC5]>  Infra  36    5180 MHz  54 Mbit/s  97      ▂▄▆█  --         no        
serenity           <MAC 'serenity' [AC1]>  Infra  36    5180 MHz  54 Mbit/s  81      ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2  yes     * 
optimumwifi        <MAC 'optimumwifi' [AN5]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  47      ▂▄__  --         no        
620480             <MAC '620480' [AN6]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  47      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
iHub_006035071645  <MAC 'iHub_006035071645' [AC7]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  44      ▂▄__  WPA2       no        
Tenda_2BEA10       <MAC 'Tenda_2BEA10' [AN8]>  Infra  5     2432 MHz  54 Mbit/s  40      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
optimumwifi        <MAC 'optimumwifi' [AN9]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  37      ▂▄__  --         no        

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/serenity]] (600 root)
[connection] id=serenity | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF3]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=serenity
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=ignore

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/New_York (based on set time zone)

country US: DFS-FCC
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 17), (N/A)
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp1s0    no frequency information.

enp0s20f0u3  no frequency information.

wlp2s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
          Channel 149 : 5.745 GHz
          Channel 153 : 5.765 GHz
          Current Frequency:5.18 GHz (Channel 36)

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp1s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp0s20f0u3  Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      3   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
      2   APs on   Frequency:5.18 GHz (Channel 36)
```

Comment: Please check the troubleshooter if it fixes your issues [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide), also check [Wireless connection troubleshooter](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting-hardware-check.html) If this doesn't help you, please get back with more details about your Wireless Adapter and we'll help you out.

Comment: please update your question with details of your computer and  wifi adapter. Also, press `Ctrl+Alt+t` and type `lspci | egrep -i --color 'network|ethernet'   ` then press enter. Add the output received to your question.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.

Comment: I can't seem to get even portions of it to fit in comments, is there a way to link to it?